# Visual Studio 2017 crashes after 10-20 minutes

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

For over a month now I've been experiencing problems with VS2017 on my home PC. I even tried [submitting the feedback to Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75111/visual-studio-crashes-randomly-and-throws-exceptio.html?childToView=76160#comment-76160). There's more info about the problems I'm experiencing there.

## The problem:

The gist of it is that VS is eating RAM like crazy. As soon as I start opening files, adding new files, using IntelliSense, building or (especially) debugging, the RAM usage [skyrockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y8yG.jpg).

After that it's only a matter of time before the VS crashes and restarts without any error message. Though there are numerous error messages throughout these breif ~20min I have with each session.

## Additional details I observed:

- Doesn't happen with Python projects, as these don't have to be built constantly. It might be eventually happening if you debug a lot, but I didn't have the chance to check that because most of my Python coding is debugged on an external device
- Size of the loaded solution doesn't matter;
- UWP and WPF seem to crash the most. Console Projects take longer to crash.
- Also affects .NET Core;
- It doesn't matter which version of .NET Framework I use;
- VS2015 worked perfectly, but I don't have it anymore after the format

## What I already tried:

- I reinstalled VS;
- I refreshed Windows;
- I reinstalled Windows;
- I checked my drives and RAM for issues - none found;
- I switched from Community to Enterprise;
- I tried disabling extensions;
- I applied some shady hotfix I found somewhere;
- Finally, I installed Rider which seems to be the best solution as of now. It still lacks many important features, though.

Is there anything else I can do/try/check? Did anyone experience (and fix) a similar issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Look into Event Viewer (Win + R > eventvwr > enter > Application in left panel) why Visual Studio crashed and ActivityLog.xml which is stored under `
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<VS version>\ActivityLog.xml`. Replace <VS version> by visual studio version number. Select at this level folder starting with number 15.

Comment: The ActivityLog file doesn't have any mentions of that, but the Event Viewer and Reliability is full of errors similar to this one: https://hastebin.com/wuyegiqogi.css

Comment: How much RAM have you installed and how much consume others applications?

Comment: @Misaz 8GB, but it was never a problem before. Besides, when VS is about to crash I usually use less than 55-60%.

Comment: What do you do in Visual Studio?

Comment: As I mentioned, nothing big. Solutions with 3 projects at most. Some WPF, UWP, console. ASP.NET Web API from time to time

Comment: have you tried WPRUI/WPA?

Comment: I voted now to close the question as "too broad" because without any detail we can't answer this.

Comment: @magicandre1981 alright.

Comment: so have you captured the ETL of the memory usage grow or not?

Comment: have you updates to 15.3 update? does this fix the issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Sticking with 2015 fo foreseeable feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a [System.OutOfMemoryException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=netframework-4.7), this means your Visual Studio runs out of free virtual address space (4GB on 64 Bit Windows for the 32Bit Visual Studio because Visual Studio is configured to be [large address aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses) and [MS refuses to release VS as 64Bit program which would fix this issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2015/12/29/revisiting-64-bit-ness-in-visual-studio-and-elsewhere/)).

To analyze the memory usage, you need to run `WPRUI.exe` (part of [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/) (which gets installed by VS2017) for some scenarios, if not, install it on your own), select `Reference Set` (Note: expand the `Resource Analysis` entry first to see all options).

[image]

and click on `Start`. Capture the memory usage grow for some 100s of MB and click on `Save`.

[image]

Open the generated ETL with the analyzer (WPA.exe) and [analyze what the process devenv.exe is doing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/wpa-reference-set#reference-set-outstanding-size-by-process).

Also zip the ETL + NGENPDB folder (important) as zip and attach it to your bug report so that Microsoft can analyze it.

Comment: I think I already did something along these lines, or, at least I used the tool that pops up when you report the the error using `Help` > `Feedback` > `Report Problem`. Is this the same thing?

Comment: I have no idea what you did during submission. Try the tool and look if you can see which command/component allocates large memory.

Comment: you have to expand the "Resource Analysis" entry first to see all options